# Http Request alternatives

Tags: php, http, curl, httprequest

I have a requirement, calling nearly 50+ URLs to fetch the data. I tried in many ways. Finally Stick with HTTPRequestPool. Because it was faster than any other methods. I tried below methods.

1.file_get_contents($url) - took about 2 mins to complete all 50 requests
2.curl - took about 45 to 50 seconds to complete all 50 requests
3.HTTPRequest - took about 20 to 30 seconds to complete all 50 requests
4.HttpRequestPool - took about 10 to 15 seconds to complete all 50 requests

But still 10 to 15 seconds is also slow, when compare to my competitors. I want to complete all the 50 requests in a max of 3 to 6 seconds. How can I achieve my target time frame. Is there any alternatives apart from the above in PHP. If yes can anybody please tell me those.

Please help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks,
Sudhakar

Comment: We need to see your code.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking others to do your homework. Network latency, DNS lookup - you completely ignored that, unless if you have no clue what those are. Also, the amount of data being received and the bandwith of the pipe that you have is a huge factor. You have mentioned none of it. You've provided no code. This question is hugely offtopic, and it appears you're severely lacking in fundamental knowledge to be able to make this budge in any direction.

Comment: Mr N.B I know about these things. But the same URLs are used by our competitors, they are receiving the response with in 5 seconds. How they are achieving. The scenarios you mentioned in the comments I understand and those same things are same for our competitors also.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my code.

```
 for($i=0;$i<$url_cnt;$i++)
 {
     $req[$i] = new HttpRequest($URLs[$i], HttpRequest::METH_GET,array('redirect'=>4,'timeout'=>5,'connecttimeout'=>7));
 }

 $pool = new HttpRequestPool();
 $pool->enablePipelining(true);

 //Attaching  the Request
 try {
    foreach($req as $r){
         $pool->attach($r);
    }
 } catch (HttpRequestPoolException $ex) { }

 try {
     $pool->send();
 }
 catch (HttpRequestPoolException $x) {}

 foreach($pool as $request)
 {
     $url_contents[] = $request->getResponseBody();
 }

 foreach($req as $r)
 {
    $pool->detach($r);
 }

 $pool->__destruct();
 unset($pool);
```